# How to take certain character in variable from data in database PHP

Tags: php, laravel, substring

I have database table named **tb_value** below. Each row have multiple value separated by comma(s).

[image]

I have a variable like this and these value will be checked to **tb_value** :

```
$input = 'D1,D2,TD,GD,GD,NS';
```

The question is, I want to check if a row contain these value :

> D1,D2,TD

The result should be showing the row with **id = 2**. How can I do that from Laravel 5.2 ?

Comment: Do you want to get the first 3 elements of a comma separated list? It's really not clear

Comment: i want to take certain character that exist in my database

Comment: This problem is not really solved, I was using different approach last year. But today I'm still curious how to do this. I already edited my question above

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you could use the php explode method

```
$inputs = explode(",", $input);
```

This returns an array of all the values separated by the comma. You could take the first three values and concatenate them to get your new input.

```
$input_new = $inputs[0] . "," . $inputs[1] . "," . $inputs[2];
```

If you want to take some of these values dynamically, you should be more specific on what you want and on the structure of your code.

Comment: my question is close to substring method, but how can I substring based on data in database

Comment: if you know your data is fixed with this type of structure, then it's better to use explode. Because in substr you have to set the position into the string you want to separate. If there are always two letters separated by comma every time, then you could do substr(",", 0), and then for every next string use an offset logic to your start position value (change the 2 to 0+3 --> the two letters and the comma).